# How do I access a control inside a custom ListBox template?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, templates, items

I was just wondering if there is anyone who could help me with accessing a control from a custom `ListboxItemTemplate`? in this case the image called Remove

My XAML for the `ListBoxItemTemplate` is:

```xml
<StackPanel x:Name="stk" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled = "true" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="82" Width="462">
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="True" x:Name="menu11">
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Share..."  Click="Sharente_Click" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black"/>
            <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="pt" Header="Pin to start"  Click="PinToStart_Click" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black"/>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete note"  Click="Delete_Click" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black"/>
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroller" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="69" Margin="1,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="369" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
        <TextBlock Loaded="NoteName_Loaded" x:Name="NoteName" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding FileNameX}" FontSize="38.667" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" Height="54" Margin="0,-30,0,0">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
        </TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Description" Height="37" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Segoe WP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="379" Margin="3,-29,0,8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0.85" Foreground="#FF787878"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ClickArea" Height="79" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,-73,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TimeDate" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="37" Margin="0,-130,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FileTime}" Width="76" Foreground="#FF7C7C7C" FontSize="22.667"/>
    <Image x:Name="Remove" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled = "True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="48" Margin="0,-70,12,0" Source="/icons/appbar.delete.rest.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="48" Tap="Remove_Tap"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

And you tap event isn't triggered?

1) Try to set Canvas.ZIndex of Image to 100 lets say, just to test if nothing is overcovering you'r picture.

2) Try to add event manualy in code:

```
 Remove.Tapped +=(s,e) =>{ //TODO: CODE };
```